# No sound at all?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

After installing a supplied update to Ubuntu 23.04 (up until then Ubuntu ran without any problem on my Dell Latitude E6500), all of a sudden there's no more sound (not within Chromium, not in YouTube, not in VLC, nowhere).
A day later however 23.10 became available. But alas, upgrading 23.04 to 23.10 did not solve the sound problem.

Additional information:

1. My machine has no additional sound card (there's just default HDA Intel).
2. I've checked answers to sound questions here but I got none the wiser.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide additional information that shows what specific procedures did you do / what checks did you perform. Did you perform [the standard tests from Ubuntu's wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/sound-nosound.html.en)? I also see you're using Ubuntu 23, which means that it should have started using pipewire for it's sound - have you tried inspecting it's services and/or resetting them?

Comment: Yes, i perormed the tests. Did not help.

Comment: How do I inspect/reset all the pipewire services?

Comment: You can try resetting the pipewire service with `systemctl --user restart pipewire` and check if it solves your problem for that specific session - if you succeed, then you'll need to check the configuration of pipewire to see what prevents it from starting up properly. Also check that you have some session manager package for it installed, for example `pipewire-media-session` or `wireplumber`.

Comment: `systemctl --user restart pipewire` produces no error (i.e. echo $? = 0) but still no sound.  `pipewire-media-session`

Comment: `henkie@henkie-Latitude-E6500:~$ pipewire-media-session`
pipewire-media-session: command not found
`henkie@henkie-Latitude-E6500:~$ wireplumber`  
..... (see file)

Comment: `pipewire-media-session`  
pipewire-media-session: command not found

Comment: `wireplumber` sorry, no file, see subsequent comments.

Comment: M 14:35:18.602227          wp-device ../lib/wp/device.c:619:wp_spa_device_new_from_spa_factory: SPA handle 'api.libcamera.enum.manager' could not be loaded; is it installed?
M 14:35:18.602293   script/libcamera libcamera.lua:173:chunk: PipeWire's libcamera SPA missing or broken. libcamera not supported.
W 14:35:18.751090  spa.bluez5.native ../spa/plugins/bluez5/backend-native.c:1840:sco_listen: listen(): Address already in use

Comment: W 14:35:18.751781  spa.bluez5.native ../spa/plugins/bluez5/backend-native.c:2390:register_profile_reply: RegisterProfile() failed: org.bluez.Error.NotPermitted
W 14:35:18.751812  spa.bluez5.native ../spa/plugins/bluez5/backend-native.c:2390:register_profile_reply: RegisterProfile() failed: org.bluez.Error.NotPermitted
W 14:35:18.754728 m-portal-permissio ../modules/module-portal-permissionstore.c:63:wp_portal_permissionstore_plugin_lookup: <WpPortalPermissionStorePlugin:0x5613e11372d0> Failed to call Lookup: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for camera

Comment: W 14:35:18.760905 m-portal-permissio ../modules/module-portal-permissionstore.c:63:wp_portal_permissionstore_plugin_lookup: <WpPortalPermissionStorePlugin:0x5613e11372d0> Failed to call Lookup: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for camera
W 14:35:18.794878 m-portal-permissio ../modules/module-portal-permissionstore.c:63:wp_portal_permissionstore_plugin_lookup: <WpPortalPermissionStorePlugin:0x5613e11372d0> Failed to call Lookup: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for camera

Comment: M 14:35:38.815841 script/policy-node policy-node.lua:614:chunk: 1 pending linkable(s) not activated in 20sec. This should never happen.

^CM 14:38:23.598289        wireplumber ../src/main.c:372:signal_handler: stopped by signal: Interrupt
M 14:38:23.600032    m-lua-scripting ../modules/module-lua-scripting/api/api.c:376:object_activate_done: <WpSiAudioAdapter:0

Comment: x5613e124cbb0> Object activation aborted: proxy destroyed
M 14:38:23.600055 script/create-item create-item.lua:80:chunk: <WpSiAudioAdapter:0x5613e124cbb0> failed to activate item: Object activation aborted: proxy destroyed
M 14:38:23.601258        wireplumber ../src/main.c:364:on_disconnected: disconnected from pipewire

Comment: I think I need to install an older Ubuntu version (the one just before 23.04: ?). How do I do that while keeping the content of the current filesystems in tact?